# CMake path for Oculus SDK

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

it might very well be that this question is ill-posed.
What I try to do is compile a code from GitHub here https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-oculus
to get the ZED stereo camera video displayed inside the Oculus.

I am working with Visual Studio for this project and unfortunately I am a total newbie with CMake. I came across several tutorials how to work with CMake and while I understand how to add include directories for a VS solution (without using CMake) I completely do not understand what these 2 beginning parts of CMake-code are trying to do:

```
SET(OCULUS_PATH "OCULUS_SDK_ROOT_DIR-NOTFOUND" REQUIRED CACHE STRING "Path of OVR SDK folder. eg: C:\\ovr_sdk_win_0.17.0\\OculusSDK")
SET(SDL_PATH "SDL2_ROOT_DIR-NOTFOUND" REQUIRED CACHE STRING "Path of SDL2 folder. eg: C:\\SDL2-2.0.
```

I don't know even the correct syntax to use for the folders. On my system I have the Oculus SDK under C:\OculusSDK and the SDL under C:\SDL. Unfortunately all the examples I've found on StackOverflow so far look completely different or are using Linux based folder script.

So could please someone explain to me what the above rows of code are trying to accomplish and what code should I use given the names of my directories?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: In `cmake-gui`, when you hit "Configure" the first time (it may emit configuration errors), in the long list of configuration entries (in red) you may found `OCULUS_PATH` and `SDL_PATH` ones. Fill these entries as their descriptions suggest, and rerun configuration.

Comment: Ok, but where do I find cmake-gui in Visual Studio 2017? Is it equivalent if I go there for the drop down menu "CMake"->"Change CMake Settings"?

Comment: I am not familiar with a way Visual Studio 2017 handles CMake projects, but "Change CMake Settings" seems the proper way.

Comment: If I do that I find a structure like `"buildRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\build.."` Is this the syntax you mean I should use? But where do I put it into the `SET()` command?

Comment: In this [blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/cmake-support-in-visual-studio-the-visual-studio-2017-rc-update/) CMake configuration entries are referred as `-Dname=value`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not see the connection in the blogpost to the above `SET()` command